# Is the group $G =\{a+b\sqrt{2}|a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

$G = \{a+b\sqrt{2}|a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ under addition:

I am going to say it's not cyclic because a,b can be distinct. I tried finding a generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it is not cyclic:  since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, the only way the sum is an integer is if $b=0$, so this means there are no additive relations between $a$ and $b$ and the group is isomorphic to it is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$.